# WCF REST web service doesn't handle post request without last slash in URI

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I implemented WCF REST api like below.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
public string Create(Article article) { .. }
```

but there's problem.

if I call this service like `mydomain.com/articles/` it works,

but if I call like `mydomain.com/articles` without last slash, it returns HTTP response code 307, Temporary Redirect.

How can I make both URI can work, or is there any wrong in my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple different ways you can have /articles redirect to /articles/. Your UriTemplate won't match an "/" entry. ScottGu has [a whole article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) on url manipulation methods, and I think any of them would work for you. It includes iis7 rewrite module (using a third party tool like ISAPI_Rewrite if you don't have iis7), and some ways to handle it in code. You could use approach #2 to explicitly rewrite in code. Or you could even create two separate methods with different UriTemplates, one for "" and one for "/".

Comment: are you sure you are talking about the rewrite for WCF and with POST Method?

Comment: I don't see why not. I know POST can be more difficult to rewrite than GET in some situations, like removing .svc, but at least one of these methods should work for moon. I've used the rewrite module for a POST in iis7 myself, however I do base my WCF projects off of [WcfContrib](https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib) so that might be helping my situation. Failing all of that though, there's no reason creating two methods for each instance shouldn't work.

Comment: Am I incorrect about this? I don't understand why I got down voted, this has worked for me.